# How to change list type from CountryData to regular text?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, text, entity, free-form-input

When you access a list of countries from CountryData the outputs are boxed and is not normal text.  How do I convert the type of items inside the list so I can modify the style? 
For example I have:

```
RandomChoice[CountryData[]
```

The Output is in an orange box. How do I get it into regular text?

Comment: `FullForm[RandomChoice[CountryData[]]]` is `Entity["Country", "Name"]` so you can take 2nd part of that to get just "Name": `RandomChoice[CountryData[]][[2]]`.

Comment: you can also use `RandomChoice[CountryData[]]["Name"]`

Comment: ... or `TextString@RandomChoice[CountryData[]]`

Comment: .... or `RandomChoice[CountryData[]] // InputForm`

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]
x = RandomChoice[CountryData[]]
```

[image]

You can use the property `"Name"`:

```
x["Name"]
```

> ```
> "Sri Lanka"
> ```

Alternatively, you can use the functions [`CommonName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommonName.html) or [`CanonicalName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html) or [`TextString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextString.html):

```
 {CommonName @ x, CanonicalName @ x, TextString @ x}
```

> ```
> {"Sri Lanka", "SriLanka", "Sri Lanka"}
> ```